# Sidebar blocks buttons

Tags: leaflet, html, mobile

Added a sidebar to my Leaflet map that is toggled by a click on a feature and contains all feature properties.

On local devices (Firefox/Chrome) everything works fine. My problems shows up only on mobile devices: If the sidebar is toggled and displayed on the map, I can't click on any other buttons on my map. They are blocked. As long as the the sidebar is shown the only thing I can do is panning through the map. When the sidebar gets closed the buttons are working again.

I tried stuff like:

```
sidebar.BringToBack();
```

and

```
examplebutton1.BringToFront();
```

but this didn't work.

Maybe it's a simple stylesheet problem because of mobile usage? For example an option that allows me to click on clickable items (marker, buttons) that are covered by the sidebar. I already set opacity to 0.5 so that I can see covered markers and features but they are not clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this: Had some issues with wrong css entries (at least i guess so...). By changing size and orientation of the sidebar i managed to solved it!